# Save a File on GWT Server

Tags: java, gwt, file-io

How can i save a file on gwt-server site in a gwt RemoteServiceServlet? The location should be folder under the war directory in tomcat. Is it in a RemoteServiceServlet possible without use FileUpload on client site?

Comment: -1 for unclear question, poorly worded, easily solved with a simple googling.

Comment: Dupe question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090670/google-appengine-not-supporting-fileoutputstream

Comment: You know that a blobstore was realised with a client request on the server and i dont wont to do a client request?

Comment: There is NOTHING like a GWT-Server Please edit your question to be more precise.

Comment: What does RemoteServiceServlet mean on server site? Isnt it a gwt-server class?

Answer (score 2):

You can write files at serverside.

```
File f = new File("/my/path/file.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write("text".getBytes("UTF-8"));
fols.close();
```

If that file should be uploaded you have to make a Upload first:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html

Maybe, this project helps: http://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-file/

**GWT: Google Web Toolkit**

A framework to create JavaScript which is running in a browser at clientside

**GAE: Google App Engine**

A Server infratructure, which allows to create applications, which are running at google server farm. Files are available via [Blobstore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview)

Comment: I dont want to upload the File and the FileOutputStream is not supported by GAE.

Comment: FWIW, my prev comment is @ChHaupt, not Christian.

Comment: I think a GWT applications always runs in the GAE and not in the JAVA VM.

Comment: No. GWT applications run in the JavaSCript VM of the browser. In fact it will work if loaded from the filesystem. GWT has NO dependency to GAE.

Comment: The client site. But the server site?

Comment: GWT runns inside a web-application container. Within a ormal container, you can use 'FileOutputStream'. If you run inside the GAE-container, you need to use the BlobStore: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview

Comment: You know that a blobstore was realised with a client request on the server and i dont wont to do a client request?

Comment: ChHaupt, GWT is a client side framework that can be used on top of ANY server side (you can make it work with PHP or ASP.net if you want).  Stop being so combative, try explaining your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload is only used for generating the correct typed HTML input tag (if you are planning to send your data not via a form).

Comment: I dont want to send data between client and server.