# How to solve Java.io.FileOutputStream is restricted class in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using **Netbeans, google app engine, java**. When I try to create pdf as follows it shows this error.

**Java.io.FileOutputStream is restricted class in Google App Engine.**

My code is,

```
Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Examplenamaaaa.pdf")));

document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("column span 2"));
cell.setColspan(2);

table.addCell(cell);

table.addCell("1");

table.addCell("Namita");

table.addCell("2");

table.addCell("Asmita");

document.add(table);

document.close();
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090670/google-appengine-not-supporting-fileoutputstream

Answer (score 1):

You're writing code that creates a PDF file on your C-drive. While this may work on your machine, it probably will not on Google App Engine.

Instead, you could try to write the PDF to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) (for example) and later send that back to the web browser so you will be able to view the generated PDF.

A `ByteArrayOutputStream` behaves exactly the same as a `FileOutputStream`, except the bytes aren't written to a file, but to a `byte[]` (hence the name). Both of them extend the [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) interface, so they can be switched without further changes to your code.

Streaming the response back to the browser [isn't supported in GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Responses)  so you could consider storing the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the [BlobStore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) in order to serve it back to the browser later on.

Comment: thanks mthmulders, but dont know how to use ByteArrayOutputStream. Could you please share any example link.

Comment: If you want to persist the PDF file online, you may also want to look at [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/).