# Google App Engine on Java 8 - java.time not available on dev. server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, java-time

I have ported my Google App Engine application to recent Java 8 runtime environment. The application works fine, with a few issues.

I have ported my code to use java.time instead of Joda time, but the app engine server throws error when responding to requests:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.ZonedDateTime is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
>
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:50)

This happens on a development server only, production server seems to be running fine.

The [documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8):

> - Doesn't impose a security manager as the Java 7 runtime does, which means your code won't be restricted by Java permissions issues.
> - Supports the standard public Java library, not just the whitelisted class subset available for the Java 7 runtime.

When searching for this error, I found mentions about file access being prohibited, which I understand, but I do not see how this applies to `java.time` package. Moreover, the mentions I have found (like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090670/google-appengine-not-supporting-fileoutputstream)) seem to be about Java 7 runtime environment.

It is not very pressing, I can stay with Joda time, but it was a surprise for me.

Is this expected, or is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with my Scala + sbt setup. Seems odd, because the documentation promises that the java8 time API is fully supported. Did you find out anything more about that?

Comment: I stay with Joda time, I did not experiment with that any more.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I use Java8 features including java.time in both the development environment and the production servers.

It is likely to be a Java 7 SDK that is being used to run your dev server. Check your build environment setup.

Make sure you have the latest app engine API jars in your WEB-INF/lib.

You also need to add java8 to your appengine-web.xml

Comment: Interesting to hear that, thanks. I followed your checklist, not much luck so far: Dev Server is running on Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin, WEB-INF/lib contains appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar, appengine-web.xml contains <runtime>java8</runtime>. My build environment is a bit unusual, I am using Scala, IntelliJ IDEA and SBT, but I do not think this should play any role here. Do you use App Engine SDK, or the new Cloud SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. It's with InteliJ plugin as it seems. Run from the maven plugin as a work around.

[image]

Comment: I confirm I am using IntelliJ as well. I will try to check your workaround - I hope I will be able to do it, I have no experience with Maven or its plugins.